# DatePicker control resizes when rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a landscape view that has a datePicker control on it, which was designed using IB. The datePicker control loads correctly the first time the view is loaded. If I dismiss the view and then load the datePicker view again, without rotating the app back to portrait first, the control resizes. If I load the datePicker, dismiss it, rotate the phone to portrait, then call the datePicker again it works fine. Is there a way to trick the app into thinking it was rotated back to portrait without actually rotating it?  Is there any other reasonable way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to rotate it on orientation, you can transform it manually. Hope I understood correctly what you were trying to explain.